# Tableview doesn't load with error "Failed to load resource" on Android 2.2

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

My app works fine on the iPhone simulator. However, when I launch the Android 2.2 simulator, the app loads (all the tabs appear) but then it crashes before my TableView appears. Here's the error:

```
E/TiJSError(  269): (main) [644,1030] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
E/TiJSError(  269): (main) [1,1031] - In ti:/titanium.js:178,19
E/TiJSError(  269): (main) [0,1031] - Message: Uncaught Error: Failed to load resource, Java exception was thrown.
E/TiJSError(  269): (main) [1,1032] - Source:       source = assets.readAsset(assetPath);
E/V8Exception(  269): Exception occurred at ti:/titanium.js:178: Uncaught Error: Failed to load resource, Java exception was thrown.
```

Does this have anything to do with memory? How can I fix this?

Thanks!!

Comment: no...that didn't work. I saw it might be a memory issue, but I added <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
to tiapp.xml to no avail...

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, and it turned out to be a memory issue.

Try inserting the following line into `tiapp.xml`:

```
<property name="ti.android.threadstacksize" type="int">32768</property>
```

Then clean the Android build folder and run the app again. I hope it works for you!